# FileNotFound - When trying to get asset file

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to get a file in the `assets`but when I run my code the `FileNotFound` exception throws. I've checked with `getAssets().list(".")` and really the android does not detect the file in the `assets` directory, but i put the file in the `assets` folder. I'm not a android expert and I count with the community help to help me to understand what am I doing wrong.

Follow bellow my code:

```
try { 
            Log.i("PEDRO", Arrays.toString(getResources().getAssets().list(".")));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Result: `[]`

```
try { 
            Log.i("PEDRO", Arrays.toString(getApplicationContext().getAssets().list(".")));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Result: `[]`

The file is in the `assets` directory.

[image: Assets]

```
try {
            InputStream input =
                    Definitions.appContext.getAssets().open("iot.neo..........com.bks");



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I know that is too much important to use the `Android Studio` for the development of the applications, but I'm doing it on eclipse because it's a legacy code that will be changed to `Android Studio` before (and I'm not a responsible for that).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove ".":

```
        try {
            Log.d("PEDRO", Arrays.toString(getApplicationContext().getAssets().list("")));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: this way I found the list of the files, but why I can't open the file and get `FileNotFound` in the `InputStream` ?

Comment: Try replace `Definitions.appContext...` on `getApplicationContext().getAssets()...` - everything should works.